# Delete bridge table rows in T-SQL that don't relate to another result set

Tags: sql, sql-delete, join

I'd like to write a delete script that deletes rows out of the bridge table (acucore_securitypermission).  Right now, this SELECT query (that will be the rows I'd like to delete) doesn't work.  I get red underlines on the line containing the "NOT EXISTS".  The only difference from the first and second snippet is the SELECT * vs. DELETE.  Also, if you have some improvements that I can make to my delete to make it cleaner (without repetition), I'm always looking for tips.

**SELECT script that doesn't work:**

```
SELECT groupname
FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
AND groupname NOT EXISTS -- <-------- I get red error underlines here!
(
    SELECT 
        groupname
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND permissions = 1
)
```

**DELETE script that I want to eventually run:**

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
AND groupname NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 
        groupname
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND permissions = 1
)
```

=====================

## UPDATE 12/1/2011 @ 3:05pm

Okay, to finish this, I want to delete from the acucore_securitypermission bridge table.  There are two keys in this table.  How can I finish this?  The SELECT query is the WHERE part containing the two key values.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
 .... ????

SELECT 
    dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid,
    dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
AND groupname NOT IN
(
    SELECT 
        groupname
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND permissions = 1
)
```

==========

## Final Answer:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
WHERE 
    'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
    + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64)) IN
(
    SELECT 
    --groupname,
    --containername,
    --dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid ,
    --dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid ,
    --dbo.acucore_securitypermission.permissions        
        'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
        + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64))
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername LIKE 'S:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND groupname NOT IN
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN 'Saliva: ' + groupname ELSE groupname END
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
        AND permissions = 1
    )
)
```

Comment: i'll be asking another question later if you want to be ready... i need to loop through all containernames that have this pattern.  The 'UI.Web.%'/'%:UI.Web.%' .. but the ending of the container names must match each other.

Comment: What dbms? MySQL? ORACLE? ...

Comment: what are the two keys? groupname  is one. What's the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "NOT IN" instead of "NOT EXISTS".

Edit 12/01/2011 15:24

For the delete, you could verify the existence of both keys by converting them to a varchar and then concatenating them into a single string.  That would allow you to make the "IN" work.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
WHERE cast(entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '-' + cast(esid as VARCHAR(64)) IN
(
    SELECT cast(entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '-' + cast(esid as VARCHAR(64))
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND groupname NOT IN
    (
        SELECT groupname
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
        INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
        INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
        AND permissions = 1
    )
)
```

Like a camel, it's ugly but it should get the job done.

Comment: You don't need to include "Edit datetime". Everyone can always see the revision history. By clicking on the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8348104/revisions) next to where it says edited. Also when you need to do NOT IN and its more then one field its way better to use `NOT EXISTS`. Comparing concatenated strings isn't SARGable. Also it makes NULLS equal which usually isn't correct.

Comment: this one worked well.  I'll post my final results at the top in a new update.I found 4 patterns that I needed to use.  I'm posting another questions so I can write a loop.

Comment: Conrad, I double checked the data.  Because the two columns we concatenated are primary keys, they will never be null in this table, so I think we're fine.  I gave you a point for that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reference the table you want to delete in the `DELETE` and `FROM` clauses

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission 
FROM   dbo.acucore_securitycontainer 
       INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission sp 
         ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = sp.esid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup 
         ON sp.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid 
WHERE  containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard' 
       AND groupname NOT IN (SELECT groupname 
                             FROM   dbo.acucore_securitycontainer 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission 
                                      ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = 
                                         dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup 
                                      ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid 
                              WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
                                    AND permissions = 1)
```

This is specific to SQL Server From the  Docs [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

> FROM `<table_source>`
>
> Specifies an additional FROM clause. This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE 
>      allows specifying data from `<table_source>`and deleting the corresponding rows
>      from the table in the first FROM clause.
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can be used instead of a subquery
>      in the WHERE clause to identify rows to be removed.

That said if you really must do it as a sub query you can use `EXISTS`

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELEC *
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission sp ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = sp.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbsp.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND groupname NOT IN
    (
        SELECT groupname
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
        INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
        INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
        AND permissions = 1
    )
   AND dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid  = sp.entityid 
     and dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = sp.esid 
)
```

Comment: the exclusion part had to include certain conditions.  I'll post my final result at the top

Comment: I lost the bits in the where clause from where.

Comment: this seems cleaner.. I'll remember this for next time ;-) up-voted you

Comment: so if really we don't need to do that hack concatenation code if we use EXISTS, because it deletes rows from that table for rows in acucore_securitypermission that get returned from that bottom query under the EXISTS, right?

Comment: so in your last query, this code "SELECT cast(entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '-' + cast(esid as VARCHAR(64))" could be replaced by "*" right?

Comment: @MacGyver. Yes I hadn't meant,to include that. I based my query on Bryce's work. I've edited it to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT groupname
FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
WHERE containername LIKE '%:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
AND groupname NOT IN -- <-------- Replace exists by IN!
(
    SELECT 
        groupname
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitypermission ON dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid = dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid
    INNER JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND permissions = 1
)
```

Comment: Your subquery return a list of groupnames, and condition is that groupname should be in the list.

Comment: You should inform about RDBMS. For example, It is not possible this delete in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Change `NOT EXISTS` to `NOT IN`